# CSS3 animation doesn't work in Chrome while works in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

The following code doesn't work in Chrome 47 and works as expected in Firefox 42:

```
@-webkit-keyframes hue {
  from { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);    }
  to   { -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes hue {
  from { -moz-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);    }
  to   { -moz-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes hue {
  from { -ms-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);    }
  to   { -ms-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes hue {
  from { -o-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);    }
  to   { -o-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}

@keyframes hue {
  from { filter: hue-rotate(0deg);    }
  to   { filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}

.change-hue-animation {
  -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}
```

Why? Am I doing smth wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the syntaxes you wrote don't even exist. And -webkit-keyframes is deprecated now. Use this to run on all browsers:

```
.change-hue-animation {
  animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: hue 60s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes hue {
  from { filter: hue-rotate(0deg);  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);  }
  to   { filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg); }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/790gzz83/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It doesn't work in IE10 though. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: It should not work, because [IE has yet to support filter](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter). AFAIK -ms-filter is not what you're looking for, since [it only provides support alpha channel filter and gradient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530752%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Ah, ok. Should I really use `-webkit-animation`? Because @Meeseeks doesn't use it

Comment: Well according to caniuse [Safari 8 and iosSafari 8.4 use -webkit-animation](http://caniuse.com/#search=animation). Those have < 1% global usage so you can decide not to use them if you want.

Comment: It's better to put first the prefixed properties and last the unprefixed ones. Good answer by the way

Comment: @vals "It's better to put first the prefixed properties and last the unprefixed ones" -- why?

Comment: Yeah I'm curious to know too. From my logic it should be prefixed rules to come later.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your animation is not triggering in chrome because it's selecting `@keyframes hue` and not `@-webkit-keyframes hue`. In which case it does not reach `-webkit-filter: hue-rotate` but uses `filter: hue-rotate` from `@keyframes` instead.

Under `@keyframes`, changing `filter` to `-webkit-filter` will work in chrome: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VincentWilkie/5k4pqmas/)

You can combine filters into one `@keyframes`, eg:

```
@keyframes hue {
  from {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
    filter: hue-rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

.change-hue-animation {
  animation: hue 10s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: hue 10s infinite linear; /* Android, Safari/Safari Mobile support */
}
```

Comment: Should I use `-webkit-animation` as well as it supposed by @Av Avt?

Comment: I rescind my comment (No, you shouldn't have to use `-webkit-animation`). If you want more compatibility across android and safari/safari mobile then add `-webkit-` :P

Comment: But @Av Avt stated that it's required for Safari 8